# does linkage rules apply to namespace just like global names?

Tags: c++

I've read [Translation units and linkage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/program-and-linkage-cpp?view=vs-2019), and it says:

> The concept of linkage applies only to global names. The concept of linkage does not apply to names that are declared within a scope. A scope is specified by a set of enclosing braces such as in function or class definitions.

It says "The concept of linkage applies only to global names" but didn't mention namespace scope. However, I saw namespace scope in some case we have to use `extern` to make some variables available in other files:

```
// constants.h
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

namespace Constants
{
    // since the actual variables are inside a namespace, 
    // the forward declarations need to be inside a namespace as well
    extern const double pi;
    extern const double avogadro;
    extern const double my_gravity;
}

#endif

// constants.cpp
namespace Constants
{
    // actual global variables
    extern const double pi(3.14159);
    extern const double avogadro(6.0221413e23);
    extern const double my_gravity(9.2); // m/s^2 -- gravity is light on this planet
}
```

So what is the official definition? Is it true that linkage concept only apply to global, maybe namespace is part of global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are orthogonal to the distinction between global and local symbols. Namespaces just augment the name of a symbol, they don't change anything else. So, if you have a global variable, and put it inside a namespace it is still global variable, with external linkage.

The exception is when you put something inside an [unnamed namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces). In this case, since there is no possible way code in one source file could reference a symbol in an unnamed namespace declared in another file, it is effectively a `static` symbol, and thus effectively has internal linkage.

Answer (score 2):

Linkage applies to names [basic.link/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3):

> A name is said to have linkage when it might denote the same object, reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name introduced by a declaration in another scope:
>
> - When a name has *external linkage*, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from other scopes of the same translation unit.
> - When a name has *module linkage*, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes of the same module unit ([module.unit]) or from scopes of other module units of that same module.
> - When a name has *internal linkage*, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation unit.
> - When a name has *no linkage*, the entity it denotes cannot be referred to by names from other scopes.

Names of variables at namespace scope have *external linkage* unless they meet certain exceptions. [basic.link/5.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#5.8) For example, non-extern const variables at namespace scope have internal linkage. [basic.link/4.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4.2)

And yes, global scope is a namespace scope. [basic.scope.namespace/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.namespace#4)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf#section.3.5) is the relevant section of the spec pertaining to linkage.

And a relevant snippet:
[image: snippet]

Indicating by default namespaces have external linkage, minus the exceptions given.